# Absolute Value function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have seen similar questions but I haven't been able to find this. I was thinking about the $\vert f \vert$ function and if it is differentiable and I require f to be continuous at f(x) = 0, then I think f is also differentiable at 0. My lame attempt at a proof:

If |f| is continuous at x = 0 then f is either positive, negative, or 0 before and after 0.

If f is positive clearly $\vert f \vert$ is positive so we need not worry about those cases.

So suppose $\vert -f \vert$. Then by continuity $\exists B_{\delta}(0) $ where $-f$ is continuous. Now $\vert f\vert$ is differentiable so $\vert f'(0) \vert = \lim_{h \to 0} (\frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}{h})$ and since $f$  is continuous at $0$ it is equal to $=\lim_{h \to 0} (\frac{0}{h})$

This result does not depend on the "$\vert \vert$" ness of $\vert f \vert$ so f is differentiable there as well.

Finally suppose $f(0) = 0$. Then $\vert f(x) \vert$ attains a minimum $\vert f(0) \vert  \geq 0$ such that $\vert f'(x) \vert = 0$. $\lim_{h \to 0} (\frac{\vert f(x+h) \vert- \vert f(h) \vert}{h}) = 0 = \lim_{h \to 0} (\frac{f(x+h) -  f(h) }{h})$ by $f$'s continuity.

I feel as though I haven't fully justified this, would someone like to help me out

Comment: What does it mean to say that $f$ is “continuous at $f=0$”?

Comment: Isn't $f(x) = x$ a counterexample? It's continuous at $x = 0 = f(0)$ but $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: Should be f(0) my b

Comment: @nbritten |f| is differentiable sorry

Comment: well, $|\cdot|$ is not differentiable 0

Comment: @edo I’m supposing that the absolute value of the function is differentiable. Then if we require f continuous f is also differentiable no?

Comment: I see, I thought the first "it" referred to $f$, not $|f|$.

Comment: @nbritten sall good

Comment: @Christheyankee: This is what you apparently try to prove: “If $f$ is continuous and $\left|f\right|$ is differentiable then $f$ is differentiable as well.” – Your proof is very confusing, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/266382 for a clean proof of that statement.

Comment: ah thnx, that is indeed it :). I promise I made a concerted effort to find another proof believe it or not. @MartinR

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

***require f to be continuous at f(x) = 0, then I think f is also differentiable at 0***

did you mean *require f to be continuous at x = 0*?

**If |f| is continuous at x = 0 then f is either positive, negative, or 0 before and after 0.**

this is not true. For example, |x| is continuous at 0 but it changes signs.

**So suppose |−f|.**

what did you mean by this? Suppose the absolute value of a function? You probably meant *suppose f is negative around some neighborhood of 0*

Next, you set |f'(x)| at 0 to equal lim $\ 0/h$ as h goes to zero, but the numerator should be f(h)-f(0). You probably meant (|f(x)|)', not |f'(x)|. It also doesn't make sense that |f'(x)| of any function f, if it exist, should be 0.

Your last statement seems reasonable. If f(0)= 0 and f reaches a local minimum at zero, and if the differential of |f| exist, it is zero. But your proof is poorly written.

If I may suggest a correction of your proof, it goes like this:

If the derivative of |f(x)| exists at a point p, and if f is continuous at that point, then f is differentiable.

**Proof:**

We only consider cases where f(p) = 0. The case where f is either positive or negative in some neighborhood of p is trivial.

we set p = 0 (it does not matter)

If f changes signs at 0, then $\ \frac d {dt} |f(x)| = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {|f(h)|}h$

Since f changes signs at 0, f is either negative when x is negative, or negative when x is positive. Suppose the former, but it really doesn't matter.

then $\ \frac d {dt} |f(x)| = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {f(h)}h = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac {-f(h)}{h}$

Note that $\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac {-f(h)}{h}$ is non positive, since h is non positive and -f(h) is non negative. Thus, if $\ \frac d {dt} |f(x)| $ exists, it equals both a non positive number, the left side limit, and the non negative number, the right side limit, thus, it is 0. Thus

$\ \frac d {dt} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {f(h)}h = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac {f(h)}{h}$ Is zero.